# Unable to install VNC Server to Windows CE 6.0

Tags: windows-7, windows-ce, tightvnc

Two computers being connected to a network. I need to run VNC Server on Windows CE 6.0, and Connect from VNC Viewer on Windows 7.

I used TightVNC for Windows 7 but I am unable to install TightVNC to Windows CE 6.0.

Please guide me from here. I tried different TightVNC installers from http://www.tightvnc.com/download-old.php but failed. As soon as I try to run installer, it says

"There is no application associated with tightvnc-2.8.5-gpl-setup-32bit. Run the application first, then open this file from within the application."

It was a .msi file, but I found a .exe installer also but when I ran it on WinCE, it says

"Application tightvnc-1.3.10-setup.exe encountered a serious error and must shut down"

Please help me here. Should I try any other VNC Server-client for WinCE and Win7?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [EfonVNC](http://efonvnc.sourceforge.net/). I see from the website that the version says v4.3 but when you download the EXE you will find it is v4.1.1.1. Deploy to your device and then start it automatically on device power-up or by code. Here is some example C# code to do just that:

```
ProcessStartInfo pinfoVNC = new ProcessStartInfo();
pinfoVNC.FileName = PATH-TO-VNC-ON-YOUR-DEVICE;
Process.Start(pinfoVNC);
```